# how to match two dataFrame in python

Tags: python, dataframe

I have two dataFrame in Python.
The first one is df1:

```
'ID'    'B' 
   AA    10
   BB    20
   CC    30
   DD    40
```

The second one is df2:

```
 'ID'  'C'  'D'
    BB   30   0
    DD   35   0
```

What I want to get finally is like df3:

```
'ID'  'C'  'D'
   BB   30   20
   DD   35   40
```

how to reach this goal?
my code is:

```
for i in df.ID
  if len(df2.ID[df2.ID==i]):
    df2.D[df2.ID==i]=df1.B[df2.ID==i]
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: So are you trying to replace zero with value ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So first of all, I've interpreted the question differently, since your description is rather ambiguous. Mine boils down to this:

df1 is this data structure:

```
ID   B            <- column names
AA  10
BB  20
CC  30
DD  40
```

df2 is this data structure:

```
ID   C  D        <- column names
BB  30  0
DD  35  0
```

Dataframes have a merge option, if you wanted to merge based on index the following code would work:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        ['AA', 10],
        ['BB', 20],
        ['CC', 30],
        ['DD', 40],
    ],
    columns=['ID','B'],
)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        ['BB', 30, 0],
        ['DD', 35, 0],
    ], columns=['ID', 'C', 'D']
)

df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='ID')
```

Now df3 only contains rows with ID's in both df1 and df2:

```
ID   B   C  D    <- column names
BB  20  30  0
DD  40  35  0
```

Now you were trying to remove D, and fill it in with column B, a.k.a

```
ID  C  D
BB 30 20 
DD 35 40
```

Something that can be done with these simple steps:

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='ID') # merge them
df3.D = df3['B']                  # set D to B's values
del df3['B']                      # remove B from df3
```

Or to summarize:

```
def match(df1, df2):
    df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='ID') # merge them
    df3.D = df3['B']                  # set D to B's values
    del df3['B']                      # remove B from df3
    return df3
```

Comment: Think you for your answer. Your description was right, that's what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Following code will replace zero in df1 with value df2

```
df1=pd.DataFrame(['A','B',0,4,6],columns=['x'])
df2=pd.DataFrame(['A','X',3,0,5],columns=['x'])
df3=df1[df1!=0].fillna(df2)
```

Comment: Maybe the description  of my question confused you, your answer  is not what I want, but I still can learn something from it. and also thank you.